# Adjusting UI based on language

Tags: iphone, localization

I am developing multi lingual app, that supports multiple language based on app settings.User can change language from app, so I am using plist to store all strings, and fetching strings based on language selected.
Problem here is, some language strings are too long which is disturbing my UI, I wanted to know what are the ways to handle it. I cannot go for Auto Layout since I have to support iOS5.0 as well. Should I create different xib for different language? What is the best solution. 
Please let me know what are the available solutions and which is the best to follow in long term.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just set a frame of UI which was disturbed at the time you change the language with condition so not much work and will work perfectly for app.

Comment: `sizeToFit` and `sizeThatFits:` are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this method to get string height and you can adjust your UI Programatically

```
-(float)calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*) text: (UIFont*)withFont: (float)width :(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{
    [text retain];
    [withFont retain];
    CGSize suggestedSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];
    [text release];
    [withFont release];
    return suggestedSize.height;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to do it programmatically as I am using xib, and I do not want to touch code if I add other language.